# How do I make text within a container centered instead of floating at the top?

Tags: html, css, clojurescript, hiccup

I have a container with two columns, an image on the left and text on the right (I'm making a landing page based on the one from [ClojureBridge London](https://github.com/ClojureBridgeLondon/clojurebridge-landing-page)). Right now the text is at the top of the column. How do I bring it down to the middle? (I'm totally new to all this so thanks for your patience).

As you can see, I tried to add a bunch of spans and empty paragraphs and they didn't do anything. What am I supposed to be doing here?

```
[:div {:class "container"}
   [:div {:class "box"}
    [:div {:class "columns"}
     [:div {:class "column"}
      [:figure {:class "image"}
       [:img {:src "img/picture.png"}]]]
     [:div {:class "column"}

      [:div {:class "content"}
       [:span]
       [:h2 "This is a header"]
       [:p "This is a paragraph."]
       [:p "More paragraph."]
       [:p
        [:a {:href   "https://clojurebridgelondon.github.io/organise-clojurebridge-london/"
             :target "_blank"}
         "Example of a link"]]
       [:span]
       [:p " "]]
      [:span]
      [:div {:class "content"}]]]]]
```

Comment: The Hiccup code translates very directly into HTML, so you don't really need a Clojure expert. You need an HTML or CSS expert.

Comment: If you are learning Clojure and HTML/CSS at the same time, I'd recommend not doing that and just learning one of them first.  It seems that the ClojureBridge landing page is using the Bulma CSS framework.  You might find the following link useful https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/#vertical-alignment